# Java for loop index : "j" isn't starting at the begining of my char Array after one loop of my index : "i"

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, indexing

I have a problem with this code, at the begening it's work well when it's found the first occurence but when it's found the second occurence it's says that there is no similar character in the string, I think it because at the second letter "p" he don't realise he have an other "p" at the begening of the array.

Some help to solve that please ?!

Thank you.

Here is my code

```
public class DuplicateEncoder {
    static String encode(String word){
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    char[] c = word.toCharArray();
    //")"
    char close = 41;
    //"("
    char open = 40;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
        if(c[i] == c[j]) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      if(count > 1){
        c[i] = close;
      }
      else if (count == 1){
        c[i] = open;
      }
    }
    String string = new String(c);
    return string;
  }
}
```

Here is the test

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;


public class DuplicateEncoderTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
      assertEquals(")()())()(()()(",
            DuplicateEncoder.encode("Prespecialized"));
      assertEquals("))))())))",DuplicateEncoder.encode("   ()(   "));
    }
}
```

Here it's my wrong result

```
expected:<)()([))()(()()](> but was:<)()([()()(((((](>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the values of the char array which is c while you are in the loop.

Changing your code into this will fix your problem:

```
static String encode(String word){
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    char[] c = word.toCharArray();
    char[] d = word.toCharArray();
    //")"
    char close = 41;
    //"("
    char open = 40;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
        if(c[i] == c[j]) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      if(count > 1){
        d[i] = close;
      }
      else if (count == 1){
        d[i] = open;
      }
    }
    String string = new String(d);
    return string;
  }
```